# Switching another screen on a 3sexs button hold press

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a new user to kivy. I want to do 2 tings in a one buttonalso O want if I just press on the button so its comming a music but if I hold the Same button for a 3 secs its switching screen. How can I do that?

I tried to have on_long_press but there is nothing called on_long_press. So please I want help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.